# Where condition on multiple relations in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have three tables in database (i.e, Post, Comment, Like). I want to fetch those posts with Comments and Likes. But only those posts where a user have either commented or liked. If a user haven't commented or liked, post should not be fetched. I know that how to fetch data with condition on separate relations. But I can't get that how I can put condition with OR in relations. If anyone knows the answer, it will be appreciated.

Here is my code for condition on individual relations.

```
$this->posts = Post::with(['comments', 'votes']);
if($field == 'comments') {
    $this->posts->whereHas('comments', function($query)
        {
            $query->where('in_user_id', Auth::user()->in_user_id);
        });
} else if ($field == 'votes') {
    $this->posts->whereHas('votes', function($query)
        {
            $query->where('in_user_id', Auth::user()->in_user_id);
        });
} else if($field == 'both') {
    // Here I want help
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it was my wrong focus. I was focusing only in `$query->where()`. But it was simple. I only need to change `whereHas()` into `orWhereHas()` for votes.

Here is updated (solution) code.

```
$this->posts = Post::with(['comments', 'votes']);
if($field == 'comments') {
    $this->posts->whereHas('comments', function($query)
        {
            $query->where('in_user_id', Auth::user()->in_user_id);
        });
} else if ($field == 'votes') {
    $this->posts->whereHas('votes', function($query)
        {
            $query->where('in_user_id', Auth::user()->in_user_id);
        });
} else if($field == 'both') {
    $this->posts->whereHas('comments', function($query)
        {
            $query->where('in_user_id', Auth::user()->in_user_id);
        });
    $this->posts->orWhereHas('votes', function($query)
        {
            $query->where('in_user_id', Auth::user()->in_user_id);
        });
}
```